# Where is the serial number on a Tamron SP 150-600mm F/5-6.3 Di VC USD G2 (A022)?

Tags: lens, tamron

On the first-gen (A011) model it was stamped faintly in the black plastic near the manufacturer location. I don't see it anywhere on the G2. I did receive a 1/8 sheet printout with the serial number on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, shoot. It's stamped right on the zoom ring, in line with the focal length index, very tiny.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Stamped right there. Barely. With feint lettering and almost not enough contrast to get an image of it. Certainly not enough contrast for my 68 year old eyes to be sure I'm reading it correctly.

[image: 3-image-stack]
(between required light angle and my position, I had to stack it)